# Rate my upper/lower split

Tags: workout-routines, injury-prevention, upper-body-workout, lower-body-strength, compound-exercises

### About me

I'm 16 years old, can bench about 45kg, do 16 pull ups, 120 kg leg press for 10 reps, 15 kg barbell biceps curl for about 6 reps

---

I've been looking through all sorts of upper/lower splits, and the one that I like the most is:

### Day 1(Lower day)

[image: Day 1]

### Day 2(Upper day)

[image: Day 2]

### Day 3 - Rest

### Day 4(Lower day)

[image: Day 4]

### Day 5(Upper day)

[image: Day 5]

### Day 6 - Rest

### Day 7 - Rest

---

As you've probably noticed I haven't added any compound movemenets, like squat and deadlift, apart from bench press to my program. Because, I was doing squats the other day, and a trainer came to me and pointed out that I was doing squats wrong, she explained that it was to a number of reasons:

1. Mostly because I am simply not strong enough to do such compound movements
2. Also I dont have the mobility and lower back strenth to squat to proper depth without rounding my spine and butt wink

As doing squats(or deadlifts) with improper form is extremely dangerous I decided to make a program without them, that I'll run for a couple of month, or just untill I get strong enough.
I left the bench press there, because imo it's a bit easier to master, and I have a friend who's been doing bench presses for quite some time, so he's helping me with the form. **But I'm not very sure if doing bench presses when you are starting out in the gym is a good thing, should I switch to doing Dumbell bench press or is there any other safer alternative?**

### About leg day

Most of the excercises are supersets, on the first excercise of the superset I'm generally doing lower reps, since I'm primarily shooting for strength gains, but the secone excercises are 20-40 reps, since they are bodyweight, so should I keep them as is(I'm planning to run bodyweight for the first 3 weeks untill I really nail down the form) or do these bodyweight movements with dumbells and reduce the number of reps?

### Why I chose this upper lower split

1. It's an upper lower split, which means that I'm going to be hitting a muscle group twice a week, which is better that a regular "bro"(bodypart) split.
2. This plan is quite simple, and has the excersises which I'm
   somewhat comfortable with.

### So how is my program overall, what would you change, etc.?

Comment: Deadlifts = picking something up from the ground, that's not dangerous with little weight to practice form unless you have a medical issue. Even my grandmother can deadlift. I'd argue that bench pressing is a lot, lot, lot more dangerous. Anyhow, do you have fun with your split? Do you like your results? Do you want to change anything? I think you have too much, it's not really efficient. I'd do more compound and less isolation/rehab stuff. But that's me. As long as you feel good about it, go ahead. You're young, you will learn. Just go ahead and learn new stuff and improve with time

Comment: Google "Bigger Leaner Stronger"

Comment: About the squats and deadlifts, the fact that you did them wrong doesn't mean you should stop doing them. It means you should learn to do them right. Doing squats and deadlifts are two of the most important exercises for a healthy, all round strong body. You don't want to end up being a guy that can benchpress 3 plates but not be able to deadlift even half of that.